# Element-by-element max values in multidimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a few multidimensional matrices of dimensions `mxnxt`, where each element in `mxn` is an individual sensor input, and `t` is time. What I want to do is analyse only the peak values for each element in `mxn` over `t`, so I would end up with a single 2D matrix of `mxn` containing only max values.

I know there are are ways to get a single overall max value, but is there a way to combine this with element-by-element operations like `bsxfun` so that it examines each individual element over `t`?

I'd be grateful for any help you can give because I'm really stuck at the moment. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
out = max(A,[],3);        %// checking maximum values in 3rd dimension
```

**Example:**

```
A = randi(50,3,3,3);      %// Random 3x3x3 dim matrix
out = max(A,[],3);
```

**Results:**

```
A(:,:,1) =

35     5     8
38    12    42
23    46    27


A(:,:,2) =

50     6    39
 4    49    41
23     1    44


A(:,:,3) =

 5    41    10
20    22    14
13    46     8

>> out

out =

50    41    39
38    49    42
23    46    44
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `max()` with the matrix and select the dimension (look the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)) on which the operation will be calculated, e.g

```
M = max(A,[],3)
```

Comment: Thanks. I must've read over that page about 10 times and it never clicked.  Serious brain lapse.